# Reading const SQLite3 db file in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I've been trying all day to write an ultra basic Android app that when given a string, reads/searches the "word" column of a sqlite3 database file I generated from CMUDict's 133000 word dictionary, (in the example below I search for the code column entry corresponding to the row that "Hello" is in in the word column)  and outputs to logcat the corresponding entry.  I know I have some methods to set values in the database but my goal is to simply search the database I already have together.

In the terminal, I can do

```
kizzlebot$ sqlite3 cmudict.0.7a.sqlite3
```

```
> SELECT code FROM cmudict WHERE word="HELLO"
```

to search the database. It returns the correct value.

But when I run my program, it just immediately crashes.  And logcat says I have a cursorIndexOutofBounds error. I have no idea what I am doing wrong since I'm not too good with reading the logcat output.

I've placed "cmudict.0.7a.sqlite3" in the assets directory located on the same level as AndroidManifest.xml.  I'm not quite positive if there are other declarations I need to make in any xml files that has to refer to the sqlite3 file. And I'm not sure if the database file was even found, but it seems so since in /data/data/packageName/database I have a cmudict.0.7a file.

```
/*
 * File: DatabaseHandler.java
 */
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cmudict.0.7a.sqlite";
    private static final String TABLE_DICTS = "cmudict";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_WORD = "word";
    private static final String KEY_CODE = "code";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_WORDS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DICTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_WORD + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CODE+ " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_WORDS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DICTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addWord(Word word) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_WORD, word.getWord()); // 
        values.put(KEY_CODE, word.getCode()); // 

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_DICTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public Word getWord(String word) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT "+KEY_CODE+" FROM "+TABLE_DICTS+" WHERE "+KEY_WORD+"=?";
        String[] r = {word};

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery,r);

        // ERROR on this line I think: cursorIndexOutofBounds
        Word aWord = new Word(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1));

        // Can't reach here.
        Log.d( "!!!!!MAJOR AVOIDED ERROR HERE", "SHIIIIIIT" );

        // return contact
        return aWord;
    }
}
```

Here is a class called word which contains the attributes of a single row in sqlite database (ie ID, word, code). and the getters and setters

```
/*
 * File: Word.java
 * Desription: SQLite3 database has columns "_id", "word", "code" (Arpabet representation). This class encapsulates a single row of the sqlite database
 */
public class Word{

    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _word;
    String _code;

    // Empty constructor
    public Word(){

    }
    // Overridden constructor
    public Word(int id, String word, String code){
        this._id = id;
        this._word = word;
        this._code=  code;
    }

    // constructor
    public Word(String word, String code){
        this._word = word;
        this._code=  code;
    }
    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting word
    public String getWord(){
        return this._word;
    }

    // setting word
    public void setWord(String word){
        this._word = word ;
    }

    // getting code
    public String getCode(){
        return this._code;
    }

    // setting code
    public void setCode(String code){
        this._code = code;
    }
}
```

Here is the Activity.  I just use it to test if I can get the "Code" column for which the "Word" column corresponds to to print to logcat.

```
/*
 * File: MyActivity.java
 */
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        Word wrd = db.getWord("HELLO");                     // I simply want to query the database for the word "HELLO", which I know for a fact is in the database because I can find it using desktop app.
        Log.d("!!!!!!!!!!!",Word.getString().toString() );
    }
}
```

I know its a lot of code to ask somebody to read, so Thank You in advance.  I'm out of ideas and I'm fairly new to Android development and sqlite

Answer (score 2):

By default the `Cursor` is pointing to an index before the first result row. You'll need to move it to the row you want before calling any of the column getters on the cursor.

If you expect a single result row, use something like this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // use row data from cursor here
}
```

If you have potentially many result rows, use somthing like this:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // use row data from cursor here
}
```

Comment: I've tried what you've said, put the if statements after the rawQuery method call but I still get errors, citing a Java NullPointerException.  It says its on the statement wrd.getCode() method call. Then logcat displays a bunch of " Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10037" lines.

Comment: Ok, I got the application to read the sqlite file perfectly but that is only if I replace /data/data/com.ex.app/database/sqlitefile.sqlite by adb push.  Why is my sqlite file not being installed with the application?